# Flow of current through human body to the floor

Tags: current

I'm having trouble understanding the flow of current from a live wire to the floor via a human.

Is the floor that we stand on conductive in nature? How does current flow through us if we stand on a wooden floor or tiled floor, and underneath the floors there'd be cement and bricks? So how does a conducting path even come into being if we are in contact with a floor?

In the same sense, how does current flow to the mud in the earth ground if the mud is non conducting in nature?

Comment: The fact that a current can flow through the materials you mention means that they're not full **isolators**. Mud **is** somewhat conducting as it contains **water** and that water will contain **ions** which can conduct electricity.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm having trouble understanding the flow of current from a live wire
>   to the floor via a human.

Some current is through conduction but also some current is due to capacitive coupling between body and earth. The human body has typically 100 pF capacitance to ground. Reliance on a conductive path does not mean current can't flow due to capacitance.

> In the same sense, how does current flow to the mud in the earth
>   ground if the mud is non conducting in nature?

Mud conducts due to several reasons, not least that water can be made to conduct quite easily.

Comment: How many people are there that have vendettas against you?

Comment: @HarrySvensson I dunno but it's strange. It seems to happen in bursts then long periods of calm!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes things goes wrong.

- Floor may become dirty, wet.
- A human can touch some conductive element connected to large capacity (Earth or other big machine).

The most frequent occurrence is wet floor.

Wet mud is conductive medium.

Comment: What happens to all the electrons that go into the mud? If there is no return path, how does current even flow?

Comment: *If there is no return path* Currents flow in loops so if there was no return path then no current could flow. Stop making assumptions like: when this is so (current flows but no loop), that cannot happen (current cannot flow) so why does it still happen? Then obviously the assumption was wrong (there is a loop).

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie, why would current flow to the ground if there is no return path? The live wire is just inserted into a copper plate right?

Comment: *why would current flow to the ground if there is no return path?* You do it again (make a conclusion based on a wrong assumption) even though I told you not to.

Comment: Speaking in non-technical terms:  Electricity wants to find a path to ground. To paraphrase a famous movie, electricity will find a way.

Comment: In ordinary power nets there is a loop on the other side of power wire.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie okay you said in your own comment that if there is no return path then no current would flow. Now, we know that current flows to the ground in case of some fault in the live wire somewhere. So if current flows to the ground, it would imply that a return path exists right? If yes, where is the return path for the current flowing to the ground?

Answer (score 0):

Everything becomes conducting at a high enough voltage. If you are standing on a dry wooden floor and touch mains live you will probably not get a shock. On that same floor and you touch a high current 20kV PSU you are in a lot of fiery trouble.